# Building Flutter app failing in XCode: Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I've been building a Flutter app with VSCode and it's run properly until going through the Flutter deployment steps (https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios) as I'm ready to launch on iOS.

I'm now getting these errors when trying to build and run:

I've looked at many other threads and nothing seems to fix it. The bundle ID matches the one I have in the Apple Developer portal and I'm trying to run on a simulator.

I'm not sure if this has to do with the second error too. I don't have an Apple device to test so have just used a simulator. It doesn't seem like I can add a simulator to my Apple Devices in the portal? Do I need an Apple Device to connect and run before deploying?

[image]

Here's the error I get when I run on vscode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Accept the latest apple developer agreement by logging with Account Holder credentials in to https://developer.apple.com

Comment: All relevant agreements have been signed and show they're active.